# Count(*) rows on two tables where row id's don't match.

Tags: mysql, join

Having a headache of a time with this:

I need to count(*) the amount of rows in two tables between now and 1 day ago where historyId in table one != historyId in table two and userId=?. I need to then return the sum of all the rows of the two tables.

If historyId in table one does equal historyId in table two it needs to only be counted as one row, rather than two.

**Query one**

```
    SELECT HOUR(date) as hr, historyId, COUNT(*) as num_rows 
    FROM webHistory WHERE userId=? AND date BETWEEN (SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    AND SYSDATE() GROUP BY HOUR(date);
```

**Query two**

```
    SELECT HOUR(date) as hr, historyId, COUNT(*) as num_rows 
    FROM locationHistory WHERE userId=? AND date BETWEEN (SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    AND SYSDATE() GROUP BY HOUR(date);
```

I've been looking at JOIN but I am completely stuck and have no idea what to even search for next let alone a route to venture and test down.

Comment: What's query one and query two? Maybe show us some sample data and desired results.

Comment: Query one is a database of searches by words, query two is a database of searches by locations. When a user searches they have the option to search by words, location or both. If searched by word, the search goes into the webHistory table. If searched by location the same happens but in the locationhistory table.If searched by both, both tables update. Now I need to count the data in the tables. The issue I have is when a user searches by both, two rows are added and it's counted as two searches, I need to count it as only one search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `union` for this:

```
select count(distinct historyid)
from (select hour(date) as hr, historyid
      from webhistory
      where userid = ? and date between sysdate() - interval 1 day and sysdate()
      union all
      select hour(date) as hr, historyid
      from locationhistory
      where userid = ? and date between sysdate() - interval 1 day and sysdate()
     ) t
group by hr;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply: How would I go about getting the count() in MySqli?

Answer (score 1):

you can use A UNION  here:

```
  SELECT HOUR(date) as hr, historyId, COUNT(*) as num_rows 
    FROM webHistory WHERE userId=? AND date BETWEEN (SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    AND SYSDATE() GROUP BY HOUR(date)
 UNION
  SELECT HOUR(date) as hr, historyId, COUNT(*) as num_rows 
   FROM locationHistory WHERE userId=? AND date BETWEEN (SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
   AND SYSDATE() GROUP BY HOUR(date);
```